# Trying to change an element's DOM's properties, but changes ignored after I use document.body.innerHTML +=. If order switched, things work fine

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I had a hard time phrasing that question's title, but could not find anything more concise.

I want to attach some event `oninput` to an element (here an `input` field). But for some reason it didn't work. I narrowed the issue to the schematic MWE (complete MWE at the end).

```
addEvent();
document.body.innerHTML += "a";
```

`addEvent()` was simply a function which changed the `oninput` property of an `input` field. My issue was that `addEvent()` was ignored.

To make sure `addEvent();` ran normally, I also modified the `value` of the `input` field, and its `backgroundColor` in the body of the function. Yet, when I ran the code, the `oninput` and `value` modifications were nowhere to be found, but the `backgroundColor` had been modified as per the function.

More mystifying to me, if I write

```
document.body.innerHTML += "a";
addEvent();
```

Things work as expected.

My question is in two parts:

- how to I fix the code of `addEvent()`, so that no matter if I write `document.body.innerHTML += "a"` before or after, the result would be the same?
- why does the `backgroundColor` run fine, while the rest seems to be ignored?

Here is my complete MWE below:

```js
function addEvent() {
    var fieldScore = document.getElementById("foo");
    fieldScore.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0,255,0)";
    fieldScore.value = "a";
    fieldScore.oninput = function () {
        console.log("bar");
    }
}

// document.body.innerHTML = buildForm();
addEvent();
document.body.innerHTML += "a";
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <form><input type="text" value="" name="foo" id="foo"></form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mwe.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Expected: same, but with `a` in the `input` field as well.

Comment: Doing `body.innerHTML += ...` will rewrite the entire `<body>`, thus destroying and recreating all elements. With that, you destroy all the events attached to them. You'll likely want to use an `append` method instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`innerHTML +=` is almost always an anti-pattern. It makes the browser do this:

- Loop through all the children and the children's children, etc., of the element on which you do it and build an HTML string.
- Append text to that string.
- Destroy all of those child elements (and their children, etc.), parse the HTML string, and replace them with new elements created as a result of parsing the string.

In that process, event handlers and any other non-HTML information on the elements that are destroyed is lost.

If you need to append to an element, use [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) or [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML). For instance:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("a"));
```

or

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "a");
```